# NaN error javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm studying for an upcoming exam and i'm having trouble with the not a number (NaN)error, I feel like its going to be something simple but i cant seem to find it, also my lecturer is very picky so a solution simple or small would be perfect.

Basically i have a simple craps game which i'm using to help study for a similar exam coming up, two dice if they equal 7 its a win, if not a loss, this part was fine until i added in a simple betting system.The error appears in the money (span id="money") section once the go button is pressed(The random number/dice part is fine), i'm pretty sure its in the winning/losses section

Any help at all would be appreciated thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Craps Game</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="dice1.png" name="firstdice" id="one" width="100" height="100" alt="dicea" />
        <img src="dice2.png" name="seconddice" id="two" width="100" height="100" alt="diceb" />
        <button type="button" onclick="toss()">Go</button>

        <p><b>Money: </b><span id="money">10</span></p>
        <p><b>Bet: </b><br/><textarea id="bet" style="text-align:center;">1</textarea></p>
        <h2 id="sometext">B</h2>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toss()
        {
            var winnings = 0;
            var loss = 0;

            //Dice
            var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            var total = random1+random2;

            firstname = "dice" + random1 + ".png";
            secondname= "dice" + random2 + ".png";
            document.getElementById('one').src=firstname;
            document.getElementById('two').src=secondname;


            var money = parseInt(document.getElementById("money").value);
            var bet = parseInt(document.getElementById("bet").value);

            //winnings
            if (total == 7)
            {
                winnings = bet*2;
                sometext.innerHTML = "You Win!";
            }
            money += winnings;
            document.getElementById('money').innerText = money

            //losses
            if(total != 7)
            {
                loss = money-bet
                sometext.innerHTML = "You Lose";

            }
            document.getElementById('money').innerText = loss
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<span id="money">10</span>` does not have a `.value` attribute. You will want to use `.innerHTML`:

```
var money = parseInt(document.getElementById("money").innerHTML);
```